# cookie consent popup language, is a language other than english

Tags: image, google-chrome, cookies, popup, setcookie

I have a Chrome image inside a German server and I have this problem that when I run that image, the cookie consent popup is displayed in a language other than English.
Why am I facing this problem and how can I change its language to English and not face this problem again?
[cookie consent popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwcD6.png)